# remapper /scan to /scan2

Tags: ros, remap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have one lidar. I need a /scan topic  for laser_scan_matcher package and need a /scan2 topic  for gmapping package.

gmapping launch :

```
    <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping"
output="screen">
<param name="scan_topic" type="string" value="scan2" />
```

laser_scan_matcher launch:

```
<node pkg="laser_scan_matcher" type="laser_scan_matcher_node"
<param name="laser_topic" type="string" value="scan" />
```

ı need a node like this :

```
<node pkg="laser_remapper" type="remapper2" name="hokuyo_remapper"/>
```

I know remap argument but how can I do that

thank you for advices...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213015/remapper-/scan-to-/scan2/) by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2015-07-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-07**:
so you want the same laser scan for the scan_matcher and gmapping? so why do you need the remapper node? you could just remap e.g. in the gmapping or set the topic to `scan`, right?

Otherwise, you could always use a [relay](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/relay)

**Comment by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on 2015-07-07**:
yes ı want different topics with same laser.
you say like that :

```
  <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" output="screen">
    <param name="scan_topic" type="string" value="scan2" />
    <remap from="scan" to="scan2" />
```

**Comment by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on 2015-07-07**:
I need separately scan topics as /scan and /scan2. because this method better then my different nodes subscribe same topic
but ı cant see result with this : rostopic echo /scan2
no publish as /scan2
and ı use this tf tree:
[http://i.imgur.com/AlhuTY6.png](https://i.imgur.com/AlhuTY6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [the documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping) there is no parameter `scan_topic` in gmapping. So the parameter will not do anything.
The remapping seems to be correct.

I'm not sure why you need the scan information of the same lidar on a different topic. What you could easily do is to create a [relay](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/relay):
`rosrun topic_tools relay scan scan2`

However, in the end, this would still be, more or less, subscribing to the same topic. This has nothing to do with your tf tree.
Which looks strange, by the way. You have tree which is only connectet through the map topic. But I guess this comes from gmapping and the scan_matcher providing a `/map->something` transform, right?

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-07-10**:
Sorry to be slightly of topic, but how generally should a TF tree general look, should it be map-> odom-> base_link-> sensors or is this dependent on the application?

**Comment by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on 2015-07-10**:
okay you are right. But if gmapping and laser_scan_matcher subscribe to same topic ( /scan) , mapping performance is good  but I see drifting and jumping a little. I think, if gmapping and laser_scan_matcher subscribe to topic diffrent topics (/scan, /scan2) , mapping has no problem.

**Comment by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on 2015-07-10**:
there is a argumnet like that and working :

```
<!-- gmapping launcher -->
 <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" args="scan:=scan2" output="screen">
```

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-10**:
Well, with the `args="scan:=scan2"` you are basically doing a remapping over the command line as you would do with `rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=scan2`. The `remap` in the launch file has the slame effect, but is better readable.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-10**:
@miguel, in most applications the tf tree is `/map->/odom->/base_link->rest_of_robot` yes. maybe you have additional frames (e.g. `/base_footprint`) in between. However, in the end, it depends on your robot and the application

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-07-10**:
I see, Thank you for the reply!